# no response using JQuerys .post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a very simple form for updating a user's status message. The form ***does work***, but I am not getting any response (using firebug the response after submit is empty).

Here is the html/js:

```
<form id="StatusUpdateForm" method="post" action="http://www.url.com/process.php">
<input name="StatusUpdate" type="text" id="StatusUpdate" />
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?=$_SESSION['user']['id']?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Update your status" />
</form>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#StatusUpdateForm").submit(function(event) {

/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault(); 

/* get some values from elements on the page: */
var $form = $( this ),
StatusUpdate = $form.find( 'input[name="StatusUpdate"]' ).val(),
userid = $form.find( 'input[name="userid"]' ).val(),
url = $form.attr( 'action' );

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
$.post( url , $("#StatusUpdateForm").serialize(),
     function( data ) {
          $('#results').html(data);
     }
);
});
</script>
```

Here is process.php:

```
if($_POST['StatusUpdate']&&$_POST['userid']){
    if( StatusMessage::set($_POST['userid'], $_POST['StatusUpdate']) ){
    echo "<div id='content'>Comment updated!</div>";
    } else {
    echo "<div id='content'>Problem updating comment. Try again.</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're expecting HTML back, you should really return just the HTML. Only JSON requests should be JSON encoded.

Comment: Is PHP throwing any errors in your httpd.log? Have you tried replacing the php code with something that always returns, to ensure you're script is getting the ajax reply?

Comment: Use Fiddler to inspect response and see if it is indeed empty or just fails to be inserted.

Comment: @Kenaniah I've tried returning only the HTML, and also changed it. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: Also, I am not big on PHP, but does `return` from the top level scope send stuff to response? Shouldn't it be `echo` or something?

Comment: @2Mellow I don't think that Kenaniah's suggestion was meant to _fix_ your problem. It was merely a suggestion best practices.

Comment: @liho1eye I used fiddler.. heres the response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2011 01:57:54 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=e06c2f913cf354f34a311306cd67e0a8; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0

Comment: So your response is empty? That means either `$_POST['StatusUpdate']` or `$_POST['userid']` evaluate to false.

Comment: But the status update does work perfectly (the sending part). its the response that is blank.

Comment: @2Mellow Please show `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: @xdazz here is what the post info looks like in the headers: StatusUpdate=Stuffers&userid=21523 .. The form itself works fine, its the blank response that has me confused.

Comment: the problem was that I used absolute path for my action url. I was not accessing an outside url, but it doesn't matter apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use absolute paths when calling ajax. **Even** if you are **not calling an outside url**.

change `http://www.url.com/process.php` to `process.php`

Answer (score 1):

Change `return` to `echo`. If it's not *outputting* anything there won't be any response to send!

```
if ($_POST['StatusUpdate'] && $_POST['userid']) {
    if (StatusMessage::set($_POST['userid'], $_POST['StatusUpdate'])) {
        echo "<div id='content'>Comment updated!</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div id='content'>Problem updating comment. Try again.</div>";
    }
} else {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
        && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
    ) {
        echo "<div id='content'>Some other error!</div>";
    }
}
```

To be extra sure it's executing, add an error callback function:

```
$.post(url , $("#StatusUpdateForm").serialize(), function(data) {
    $('#results').html(data);
}).error(function(eventData) { 
    alert('error: ' + eventData); // try that
});
```

Or (preferred):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
        $('#results').html(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // alert(errorThrown);
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this, doesnt work. Ive updated the question, though.

Comment: I added the error callback and I am getting an error.. but the form does execute because it works... I just dont get the response html.

Comment: Style note: if you gonna use Deferred pattern, then you should probably do so for both fail and done events.

Comment: @mmmshuddup I think evenData is an array... this is what it says "error: [object Object]"

Comment: Try `alert(xhr.statusText);` instead then.

Comment: @mmmshuddup I cant seem to get the $.ajax code you gave me to work. its not sending the POST data. I tried adding `data: $(this)`

Comment: @mmmshuddup if I change `eventData` to `xhr.statusText` the error no longer alerts.... this is strange....

Comment: the problem was that I used absolute path for my action url. I was not accessing an outside url, but it doesn't matter apparently.